# What is the difference between bulk copy (bcp) and bulk insert in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, bulkinsert, bcp

What is the difference between bulk copy (bcp) and bulk insert?

Is there a switch to export all of the data in all of tables in a database for bcp?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- bulk copy is an utility program: [bcp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)
- [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) is a Transact-SQL statement.

bcp.exe uses BULK INSERT to do its job. It's the same relation that the one between sqlcmd.exe (a tool) and SELECT (a statement).

There is no 'switch' to export all tables in a database. There is however an [export and import wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) which is based on SSIS, not on bcp.

Comment: tanx remus, is there any switch that override some of data in destination database?

Comment: No. Your question indicates that you need to design an ETL job using SSIS, not a bulk insert.

Comment: can you describe ETL more for me?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx